# PrintDocument send Document Name to printer

Tags: c#, printing

Using C# and the PrintDocument() Class, does anyone know how to include the Document Name when sending the print job to the printer?  Where the document name would appear on the LCD, it's always blank.

Comment: Setting the DocumentName property did not achieve this goal on any printers (many makes/models available).

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.drawing.printing.printdocument%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> PrintDocument.DocumentName: Gets or sets the document name to display (for example, in a print status dialog box or printer queue) while printing the document.

Code sample:

```
// Provide a friendly name, set the page number, and print the document.
printDoc.DocumentName = "My Presentation";
```

Comment: I set printDocument1.DocumentName = "TEST"; and the LCD on the printers says the document name is "S".  The lone letter S...

Comment: Yet in the Windows Print Queue window it appears with the correct file name... any ideas?

Comment: File names appear on the printer correctly from applications such as Notepad, Paint and Word.

Comment: I can't find anything on the internet about your issue, perhaps it lies with the .net framework and your printer not sending the document names correctly? The property `DocumentName` seems to be the only known way to change the name of the document, as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt.  It's very odd.

Comment: The first time the print job is sent it's called S.  The second it's called U.  After that, blanks.